# How to connect wallet / set caller for Read Contract buttons on Etherscan?

Tags: blockchain, etherscan, view, msg.sender

When I use the "Read Contract" tab on Etherscan, it works even if I didn't "connect" by Web3 wallet. It seems to be reading the blockchain passively.

The thing is, one of the functions uses `msg.sender` or even `_msgSender()` to check, for example, is the caller is the `owner` of the contract. And calling it from Etherscan returns `false`, while `remix` returns true (because it's connected to the wallet).

What does Etherscan use, and is there a way to set the caller for the Read Contract methods? I tried doing it in Write Contract, but it doesn't seem to be used for Read Contract anyway. Probably just caches the info?

Comment: When you try to interact with such method, it does not even display the error response on etherscan even though you can see it in the Network tab of DevTools.

Comment: Interestingly enough, by removing the `view` keyword from the function, I was able to call it from the **Write Contract** tab with a wallet connected, but I could not understand the value returned from the tx. The response did not appear in etherscan below the field.

Comment: Is Etherscan just flawed in this way with no fix?